# How to subtract a median using complex condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, lapply

I have dataset

```
df=structure(list(SKU = c(11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L
), stuff = c(8.85947691, 9.450108704, 10.0407405, 10.0407405, 
10.63137229, 11.22200409, 11.22200409, 11.81263588, 12.40326767, 
12.40326767, 12.40326767, 12.99389947, 13.58453126, 14.17516306, 
14.76579485, 15.94705844, 17.12832203, 17.71895382, 21.26274458, 
25.98779894, 63.19760196), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
    acnumber = c(137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
    137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
    137L, 137L, 137L), year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), .Names = c("SKU", 
"stuff", "action", "acnumber", "year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

The action column has only two values 0 and 1. 
As we can see there is 3 observations by stuff of 1 category and 18 obs by stuff of zero category.

I need
`-`Calculate median for the stuff  variable only for category 1 (it is equal to 25.98779894) without zeros.
As we can see  there are zeros between one, they need to be removed, as well as negative values, if they exist.
I.e, as if the dataset was like this:

```
structure(list(SKU = c(11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L
), stuff = c(8.85947691, 9.450108704, 10.0407405, 10.0407405, 
10.63137229, 11.22200409, 11.22200409, 11.81263588, 12.40326767, 
12.40326767, 12.40326767, 12.99389947, 13.58453126, 14.17516306, 
14.76579485, 15.94705844, 17.12832203, 17.71895382, 21.26274458, 
25.98779894, 63.19760196), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), 
    acnumber = c(137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
    137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
    137L, 137L, 137L), year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), .Names = c("SKU", 
"stuff", "action", "acnumber", "year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Also i need calculate the median for the last three observations by stuff variable for category 0, which go before the first one,
in our case it is 12,40326767

then subtract from the median for category 1 the median by category 0 and multiply by the number of one, in this case 3.

(25,98779894-12,40326767)*3=40,75359381

How can I do this operation?

as output i expect

```
SKU     stuff     action    acnumber    year    value
11202   8,85947691  3          137      2018    40,75359381
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
df %>%
  group_by(SKU,acnumber,year) %>%
  summarize(value = 3*(median(stuff[action==1]) - median(stuff[match(1,action)-3:1])),
            stuff=first(stuff),
            action = sum(action)) %>%
  select(SKU,stuff,action,acnumber,year,value)

# # A tibble: 1 x 6
# # Groups:   SKU, acnumber [1]
#     SKU stuff action acnumber  year value
#   <int> <dbl>  <int>    <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1 11202  8.86      3      137  2018  40.8
```

Comment: Moody_Mudskipper, very, great, but can you help me in similar question, but separated by group. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817958/how-to-subtract-a-median-using-complex-condition-by-group-in-r. If can answer in this topic, i just delete new related post.

Comment: I'm going to take a look, but in my answer I already made it general for several groups though the `group_by` statement

Comment: Moody_Mudskipper, last question. from data by stuff for  1 category , median must be calculated without minus or 0 value (1,2,3,-4) -4 must be delete. How to do it?